# A expressão: "tomá-lo ao pé da letra"

Tags: etimologia, expressões, diferenças-transatlânticas

Hoje comprei um livro editado no Brasil em 1989, tradução de um insígne autor francês. (Esta obra nunca foi editada em Portugal, e a tradução está um primor.)

No livro vem esta expressão:

> "uma citação entre aspas"(o original em Alemão): assim falava o autor XXX. É preciso **tomá-lo ao pé da letra**. (...)

A minha pergunta é tanto a origem da expressão "ao pé da letra" (que suponho vir do "pé da imprensa" dos livros antigos). Mas mais ainda, se a expressão:"**à letra**" que é muito comum no quotidiano é uma forma simplificada da outra?

(Eu já tinha visto a expressão "tomar ao pé da letra" mas é raro e suponho que caiu em desuso. Qualquer contexto que possam acrescentar é bem vindo.)

**EDIT:** Com ajuda do precioso contributo dado na resposta aceite à pergunta, consegui encontrar [um artigo na *Aleteia.org*](https://fr.aleteia.org/2018/10/26/ces-expressions-qui-ont-une-origine-biblique-au-pied-de-la-lettre/) (considerada [uma plataforma com crediblidade](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleteia_(plataforma))) que identifica a expressão **"tomá-lo ao pé da letra"** como referindo-se, na sua origem, ao versículo:

> **2Cor3:6.**  (...) uma nova aliança, não da letra, mas do Espírito; porque a letra mata, enquanto o Espírito dá a vida.
>
> [Bíblia da  Província Portuguesa dos Frades Menores Capuchinhos.](https://capuchinhos.org/biblia/index.php/2Cor_3)

Comment: No Brasil, não me parece que seja rara e nem esteja em desuso. Na linguagem falada, é muito comum utilizar "ao pé da letra" com o significado de "literalmente". Sim, conforme o dicionário [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/P%C3%A9/), a expressão *à letra* é sinônimo (bem raramente usada no Brasil, eu presumo).

Comment: @Pedro deixa-me confirmar se percebi bem, no Brasil a expressão "à letra" é MENOS usada que "ao pé da letra"? E é frequente o uso desta última no discurso verbal? (Se a resposta a ambas as perguntas for sim, em Portugal é o contrário.)

Comment: Exatamente isso. Pelo menos conforme a minha percepção.

Comment: Bom, se és brasileiro sabes do que falas. Em Portugal o "á letra" é comum e o "ao pé da letra" não é nada frequente. Se quiseres converte o teu comentário em resposta e eu aceito a resposta.

Comment: "ao pé da letra" é comum no Brasil.

Comment: Mais um brasileiro confirmando: "ao pé da letra" é bastante comum; nunca tinha ouvido falar de "à letra".

Comment: Um exemplo: Cuidado com ele.  Você não pode levar ao pé da letra tudo o que ele diz.

Comment: Pergunta interessante. Encontrei a referência ao 2 Coríntios 3:6 em vários sítios, mas olha o que diz a New Jerusalem Bible a propósito desse verso: "This is not an observation about the ‘letter’ as opposed to the ‘spirit’ of a text: the contrast is between the written external Law of the OT, and the Spirit, the interior law of the NT." E faz sentido. Da leitura em contexto resulta claro que "Espírito" é o espírito de Deus, não dum texto. E "nova aliança" contrasta implicitamente com antiga aliança. No pensamento de S. Paulo (autor das cartas aos Coríntios), a nova aliança em Cristo >>

Comment: >> substitui a antiga aliança entre Deus e Israel, esta assente em lei escrita, enquanto na altura em que S. Paulo escreve, ainda não existia um Novo Testamento escrito. O pensamento de S. Paulo foi o que prevaleceu, por isso os cristão ficaram dispensados de observar a lei do Antigo Testamento, e podem por isso regalar-se com carne de porco, e não precisam de levar o prepúcio à faca.

Comment: Bad-coder, não compreendo: a New Jerusalem Bible implica que "letra" no verso em questão se refere à lei do Antigo Testamento e não a 'sentido literal'; então não é nada claro que esse verso seja a inspiração da locução "à letra". Se a minha referência ao prepúcio te ofende, eu posso tirá-lo; mas é um dos melhores exemplos da lei judaica que os cristão não precisaram de seguir (portanto, da rotura ente nova e antiga aliança, a que o verso alude). Eu na tua pergunta já votei, já aqui há uns dias; fui o único até agora. Quanto à resposta, bem, temos critérios diferentes.

Comment: Não me parece impossível que pessoas tenham feito associações dessas, tipo: a nova aliança é do Espírito, a antiga era assente na lei escrita; os fariseus insistiam na observância estrita da lei; e daí passar-se a usar *à letra* para 'cumprimento estrito'. Não me parece impossível, mas então seria necessário prová-lo, encontrando comentários desse tipo em documentos por volta de 1280 (*a la lettre* está atestado em 1280) mostrando que as pessoas fizeram esse tipo de associações, ou outra associação de *à la lettre* ao verso em questão. Caso contrário, não passa de uma hipótese especulativa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se trata de uma refêrencia bíblica e quer dizer literal ou literalmente,aqui vai a ideia de literal:

> Veja que há uma variação nas palavras de São João Crisóstomo em
>   relação a esta passagem que também é uma tradução válida “não ser
>   sábio além do que está escrito” por causa de variações nos manuscritos
>   (Koiné e Bizantino) que contém uma palavra φρονεῖν (phronein) que ao
>   pé da letra [[literalmente]]) é traduzida como “saber", "pensar", "ter
>   uma opinião” e está no particípio passado.

[ao pé da letra](https://seibonokishi.blogs.sapo.pt/nao-ultrapasse-o-que-esta-escrito-a-144238)

> Utilizam-se das interpretações pessoais, eivadas de vaidade e
>   profundamente fanatizadas, para interpretarem ao pé da letra inúmeras
>   passagens bíblicas

[ao pé da letra](https://oeremitaespirita.blogs.sapo.pt/2010/08/)

Aqui encontrei a referência à Bíblia, com uma explicação em francês:

Se usa em francês e também escrito em francês em inglês (consulta o Merriam Webster).

> > Dès le XVIe siècle, cette expression "prendre au pied de la lettre" a le sens de "comprendre une chose dans le strict sens des mots". Il
> >     s'agit d'une allusion à la Bible dans laquelle une lettre des
> >     Corinthiens met en avant la nuance qui existe entre ce que l'on peut
> >     dire ou écrire et le sens réel des mots, les sous-entendus.
>
> Tradução da primeira frase: A partir du século XVI, a expressão "**tomar** (ou entender) **ao pê da letra**" quer dizer entender uma coisa segundo o sentido estrito das palavras.
>   [etc.]

[au pied de la lettre](http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/151/au-pied-de-la-lettre/)

Os tradutores usam muito essa expressão para dizer: traduzir literalmente.

Geralmente, traduções (de textos) ao pé da letra são péssimas e outras vezes traduçôes de certas expressão são literais: ao pé da letra = au pied de la lettre....:)

Seria interesante procurar o texto da Biblia mas daria muito trabalho.

Acho que é evidente que a expressão veio do francês.

Comment: P.S. Fiz um edit no post original se quiseres reparar.

Comment: @bad_coder to the letter is not au pied de la lettre. Au pied de la lettre is used in English. The meanings are different and the expressions are used in different circumstances.